# Can't delete git repo in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

After upgrading Egit in Eclipse Indigo I can't delete a repo from inside Eclipse once it's been created. If I right-click on the repo from the git repositories view and go to delete, nothing happens. To delete it, I have to close Eclipse then manually delete the repo from the git folder. I tried deleting the git and ssh folders, upgrading Java and upgrading to Eclipse Kepler with the same result.

I have:

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Eclipse Kepler (64bit) -> C:\Program Files
- Egit: 3.0.0.201306101825-r
- ssh folder -> C:\Users\mike
- git folder -> C:\Users\mike

  ---

**EDIT**
The log file shows this regarding Egit:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-06-30 19:09:53.595 !MESSAGE
>   Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of
>   native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level Git settings which
>   might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git
>   installation directory. The most important of these settings is
>   core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true
>   in this system level configuration. The Git installation location can
>   be configured on the Team > Git > Configuration preference page's
>   'System Settings' tab. This warning can be switched off on the Team >
>   Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

Comment: After you select *Delete*, is an error message logged in the *Error Log* view?

Comment: Yes at least 50 different errors. Unhandled event loop exception ect. ect.

Comment: 50 errors for the one action? Try clearing the view first, to get rid of old errors. Then, could you try to find all errors where egit is in the stack trace and [file a new bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the folders:

- eclipse
- .eclipse
- ssh
- git
- workspace

and the file gitconfig. Then I reinstalled Eclipse Kepler. But the problem shouldn't have happened when I upgraded Egit back when I was using Eclipse Indigo. I did file a bug.